# How to wait before opening command at selenium tests phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am writing the test (PHPUnit and selenium) for my contact that include google maps slider.
I am writing the following function in my test.

`public function testContact() {
        $this->open("/contact");
    $this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("id=username"));
        $this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("id=useremail"));
        $this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("id=usermessage"));
        $this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("css=input.submit_button"));
}`

But I got and error message
`Timed out after 30000ms` and show the errors line at `$this->open ("/contact");`
How I can wait for opening my test page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can wait like that `$this-setTimeout(5000);`